# how to resolve action bar not supporting for icon and text change setup?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

i am unable to debug this problem.i.e.when i am trying to change text name and put an icon for action bar its not supporting..i mean it is throwing an error like

```
02-06 11:43:39.964 9510-9510/com.example.brahmaiah.app1_menu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.brahmaiah.app1_menu, PID: 9510
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brahmaiah.app1_menu/com.example.brahmaiah.app1_menu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.brahmaiah.app1_menu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

my MainActivity.java

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_image3);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and i had support of v 7 and v 4 libraries.i am also tried to get execution like this in my activityi.e.actionBar.getSupportActionBar();.
kindly help me in that to get out of it debug.
i think no need of manifest.xml..because i had tag correctly with minversion:7 and maxVersion17..thanks in advance!!
and app theme also like...light.noActionBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Toolbar` as actionbar first then use `getSupportActionBar()`

You need to change the below code

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_image3);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

to

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_image3);
```

Comment: thank you very much sir..its worked through code..but when i am trying to change through manifest file like<activity><android:icon=R.drawble.ic_image3>its doest  reflect on my layout action bar.but when i am trying to change through code its appted..may i know the reason for that from you sir?

Comment: because you have toolbar acting as actionbar. so you need to set icon for that

Comment: Normally I wouldn't do this but my question has got very little views and I have no idea how to do it so would you be able to take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729545/reflection-in-background-android) please? I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

use `AppCompatActivity`

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

TRY this code :

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_dark);
    actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title));
```

Comment: thank you sir,but i am extending AppCompatActivity class only..so i had those import packages already.anyway thanks for your kind replay...

Comment: yes it is byDefault when you use AppCompatActivity but i think you should try this ActionBar in your java file will be more easy @brahmyadigopula